# How to return elements with positions < 5

Tags: xpath, xquery

I need to return the top 5 `<Concelho>` elements with the most `<Habitante>` grandchildren from `Ano` = 2001, but I'm having problems.

My code:

```
for $x in doc("Camaras.xml")/Portugal/Concelho
order by xs:integer($x/Habitantes/Habitante[@Ano = "2001"]) descending
return data($x[position() <= 5])

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE Portugal SYSTEM    "CamarasDTD.dtd"> <Portugal>
    <Concelho Nome="Arganil " id="0">
         <Contactos>
              <Email>geral@cm-arganil.pt</Email>
              <Telefone> +351 235 200 150</Telefone>
              <Fax> +351 235 200 158</Fax>
         </Contactos>
         <Localização>
              <Codigo-Postal>3304-954 Arganil</Codigo-Postal>
         </Localização>
         <Mapa src="http://cim-regiaodecoimbra.pt/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/3D_arganil.png"    />
         <Habitantes>
              <Habitante Ano="2001">2001</Habitante>
              <Habitante Ano="2011">12145</Habitante>
         </Habitantes>
    </Concelho>
    <Concelho Nome="Cantanhede " id="1">
         <Contactos>
              <Email>geral@cm-cantanhede.pt</Email>
              <Telefone> +351 231 410 100</Telefone>
              <Fax> +351 231 410 199</Fax>
         </Contactos>
         <Localização>
              <Codigo-Postal>3060-133 Cantanhede</Codigo-Postal>
         </Localização>
         <Mapa src="http://cim-regiaodecoimbra.pt/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/3D_cantanhede1.png"    />
         <Habitantes>
              <Habitante Ano="2001">37910</Habitante>
              <Habitante Ano="2011">36595</Habitante>
         </Habitantes>
    </Concelho>
    <Concelho Nome="Coimbra " id="2">
         <Contactos>
              <Email>geral@cm-coimbra.pt</Email>
              <Telefone> +351 239 857 500</Telefone>
              <Fax> +351 239 820 114</Fax>
         </Contactos>
         <Localização></Portugal>
```

The ordering is working correctly, but it's retuning all `<Concelho>` elements.

Comment: you are only showing 1 `Concelho`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the sort, then filter:

```
let $foo :=
    for $x in doc("Camaras.xml")/Portugal/Concelho
    order by xs:integer($x/Habitantes/Habitante[@Ano = "2001"]) descending
    return $x

return $foo[ position() <= 5 ]
```